# Kinect V2 Infrared Face Points Tracking does not show proper postion for Co-ordinates

Tags: c#, windows, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I have implemented Green-Screen(Background Removal) functionality in my code using Kinect V2 sensor. Now i need to detect position of face points like eyes, nose and mouth.

Green-Screen is in the depth stream so using `FacePointsInColorSpace` method I'm not able to get proper position of the face objects.

Also one of the `FacePointsInInfraredSpace` method is available for that and it also tracks the objects but display wrong position. It's difficult to understand that Infrared & Depth steam both have 512 * 424 resolution so why it not detects the proper position of face points.

I have placed my IR stream face points detection image using `FacePointsInInfraredSpace` method at here : [image: Face Tracking Using <code>FacePointsInInfraredSpace</code>]

So how to get proper position of an face points in infrared stream so that i can use it inside the Green-Screen implementation.

Also, one of my another question is that How to get proper position of face-points when we uses image frame size manually Eg. In 1920 * 1080 resolution it gives proper image frames tracking for face-points but now if i set frames size is as 960 * 540 or any one which i want to set then how can i get proper position of an face-points.

Comment: I am trying to capture IR images with Kinect2. But it shows black screen. Can you guide me how you made it work

Answer (score 3):

Hi Anand i am not sure that this blog contain exact answer that you want but may be this help you [Kinect for Windows version 2](http://pterneas.com/2014/02/20/kinect-for-windows-version-2-color-depth-and-infrared-streams/)

Comment: Thanks Manoj for your support !! this artcle helps me a lot & also get several new things about Kinect.